# How do I make a foreign primary key that references to another primary key that is made of multiple foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've currently got something like this on one table:

```
create table NetWorth (
    id int,
    id_movie int foreign key references Movie(id),
    primary key (id, id_movie)
    )
```

And want to make a reference to its primary key, which is made of up 2 attributes, its own ID and the ID of the Movie table. Currently, I was thinking something like this:

```
create table Merchandising (
    id_networth int foreign key references NetWorth(id) primary key,
    value float
    )
```

But obviously it's wrong, because it's missing the second key reference, and I don't know how to implement it in the second table. So could you guys help me out?

Comment: If the primary key you want to reference is made up from multiple columns, **all** foreign keys referencing it **must also** have and use **all those columns**. You can't just reference half a primary key - it's all or nothing.

Comment: Is `NetWorth.Id` unique?  If so, why not make that the primary key?  If not, defining a foreign key reference on a non-unique field makes no sense.

Comment: @marc_s That would definitely make sense. But what is the correct syntax? I've tried different things, but I haven't had success in finding the correct syntax to reference both columns.

Comment: @sstan Yes, it is unique.

Comment: Then the correct primary key is `id`, not `id, id_movie`, in which case you'll have no trouble defining your fk on the `Merchandise` table.

Comment: This is a weird design. If this is really your schema (and not a modification for illustrative purposes), why have the NetWorth table have its own independent primary key? That is, presumably each movie only ever has one net worth, so id_movie should be sufficient. Similarly for Merchandising. It seems you're making it too complicated for a gain that I'm having a hard time seeing.

Answer (score 3):

If the primary key you want to reference is made up from multiple columns, all foreign keys referencing it must also have and use all those columns. You can't just reference half a primary key - it's all or nothing.

Since the FK references **two columns** in your case, you cannot apply the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint syntax to a single column - use this instead:

```
create table Merchandising 
(
    id_networth int 
       constraint PK_Merchandising primary key,
    id_movie int,
    value float,

    constraint FK_Merchandising_Networth
       foreign key(id, id_movie) references NetWorth(id, id_movie) 
)
```

And I would also recommend to **always** specify an **explicit name** for your constraints - both your primary key constraints, as well as your foreign key constraints (and also all others you might have).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tested it yet but I'm pretty sure this is what I need and that it works. However, could you explain what that piece of code does? I wish to understand what's going on there. I've analyzed it but I'm having trouble understanding what it does exactly.

Comment: @KaiZ: not sure what you mean - the `constraint...` just defines the FK constraint, gives it a name, defines it as a foreign key constraint based on two columns that reference the `NetWorth` table (and its two columns).....

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in the comments, `NetWorth.Id` is unique, and so is probably the only column you should define as the primary key, not `id, id_movie`.

Once you make that change, you will no longer have an issue creating your foreign key reference from the `Merchandising` table.

**EDIT**:

Your table creation statements could look like this (though I agree with marc_s that you should explicitly name the constraints):

```
create table NetWorth (
  id int primary key,
  id_movie int foreign key references Movie(id)
)

create table Merchandising (
  id_networth int foreign key references NetWorth(id) primary key,
  value float
)
```

Comment: I think I need both because I'll need the contents of NetWorth.Id based on `Movie.Id` at the same time. In practical terms, the net worth is on a per movie basis. Each movie should have a different net worth.

Comment: Not having `id_movie` as part of the primary key does not prevent that same column from having a foreign key reference to `Movie(id)`.  So I fail to see the problem.  I edited my answer to show you what it could look like.